# Is it possible to read the SECRET KEY from Django settings.py by other apps?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I want to use the Django SECRETE_KEY for creating my JWT (Json web token). Is it possible to read the django secrete key from all apps under a django project?

Please advise me on if it is a good practice to use the django secrete key for internal app logic.

Comment: If by any chance you are using django-restframework, there is an option that django secret can be use in the settings.py on JWT_AUTH configuration http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#additional-settings

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Now I am using django-rest-framework-jwt.

Answer (score 0):

I use .env file to do it. Try use .env that you can refer it to other file as well

https://github.com/jpadilla/django-dotenv

https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv

This link will help how to use .env to set it up

Answer (score 0):

Create an env file, import it into settings, 
eg:

assume settings.py and your env file is settings_top_Secret.py

In settings.py

```
from . import /PATH_TO/settings_top_Secret

SECRET_KEY = settings_top_Secret.SECRET_KEY
```

and in your settings_top_Secret.py

```
SECRET_KEY = '7984)0_beumt0)wuvk*y%))0_beumt0)wuvk*y%(vss-x-7z_'
```

And always, refrain from uploading settings_top_Secret to accessible path in live server, or in case of git, include it in gitignore.